# Using resource route to create dynamic URL's which is not based on id

Tags: php, laravel, database, inertiajs

I have a database which contains id and randomString columns (also unique value), i set up a resource route so i can dynamically get the url of the database like this /editor/1 etc.

In standard use of the resource controller the show function would get the id from the Editor model in this case, is there anyway to get around this so I can access the info from the database like this: /editor/{randomString} ?

```
public function show(Editor $editor)
{
    return inertia(
        'Editor/Show',
        [
            'editor' => $editor
        ]
    );
}
```

```
<template>
    <div v-for="editor in editors" :key="editor.id">
        <Link :href="`/editor/${editor.id}`">
Go to id
        </Link>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

defineProps({
    editors: Array,
})
</script>
```

```
<template>
<p>show</p>{{ editor.id }}
</template>
<script setup>

defineProps({
  editor: Object,
})
</script>
```

```
Route::resource('editor', EditorController::class);
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Editor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class EditorController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return inertia(
            'Editor/Index',
            [
                'editors' => Editor::all()
            ]
        );
    }

    public function show(Editor $editor)
    {
        return inertia(
            'Editor/Show',
            [
                'editor' => $editor
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: so you no longer want to find that type of resource by id everywhere? or just in certain places you want to use a different field to do the lookup?

Comment: I would like it to do both, but found an answer that points it out as posted below :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use implicit model, you just do:

```
//you can use any variable name instead of $randomString
public function show($randomString)
{
     //your code
}
```

If you want to change the column, you can use getRouteKeyName() method, such as:

```
class Editor extends Model
{
   /**
   * Get the route key for the model.
    */
    public function getRouteKeyName(): string
    {
       return 'slug';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to simply create a route, import the model you want to returned to the route, and pass in the column name {editor:configuration}

```
use App\Models\Configuration;
```

```
Route::get('/configuration/share/{editor:configuration}', function (Configuration $configuration) {
    return $configuration;
});
```